# How to block mails from a specific server in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

I am getting mails daily from different mail address like `ry8029@fastmail.fm` or `ry1532@outlook.com` etc. Since the mail IDs change daily, I can't filter those mails.

I checked the emails’ origin.

```
X-Received: by 10.224.75.69 with SMTP id

x5mr811082qaj.39.1381914914355;

Wed, 16 Oct 2013 02:15:14 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: <ry8029@fastmail.fm>
Received: from server.rupyen.info

(server.rupyen.info. [173.245.7.224])

by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id c11si34872774qey.80.1969.12.31.16.00.00

(version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);

Wed, 16 Oct 2013 02:15:14 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: neutral (google.com:  173.245.7.224 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of ry8029@fastmail.fm) client-ip=173.245.7.224;
```

I found that for every mail, the mail server is the same: `server.rupyen.info`.

How can I block/filter these mails?

Comment: If these are spam email, report them and their originating server. If not, you could contact the server maintainers and remove your email from their list.

Comment: It's very easy if you are a Google Apps user (not sure if it's your case)

Answer (score 2):

Filters on headers are extremely limited and don't allow to do what you want. See [Gmail advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) for the list of filter operators.